# Coordinates of children of canvas element

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas, coordinates

There are a few rectangles inside a `canvas`. How can I get the coordinates of the rectangles wrt canvas using the `Name` of rectangles in `C#` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using TransformToVisual. There's a good example here: [Visual.TransformToVisual MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visual.transformtovisual.aspx)

From the page for Posterity:

```
<StackPanel Name="myStackPanel" Margin="8">
  <TextBlock Name="myTextBlock" Margin="4" Text="Hello, world" />
</StackPanel>

// Return the general transform for the specified visual object.
GeneralTransform generalTransform1 = myStackPanel.TransformToVisual(myTextBlock);

// Retrieve the point value relative to the child.
Point currentPoint = generalTransform1.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```